# Login page for users trying to access my hotspot

Tags: networking, login, hot-spot

I want to show a login page for users who try to access my hotspot. And then once they login i want to capture their mac address. Its like a small captive portal for my laptop.

Any advice??

Comment: You might want to put [DD-WRT](http://dd-wrt.com/) on your router.

Answer (score 1):

How are you connected to internet? A mean is there any kind of router, or hotspot is a router itself?

If you have some kind of router (I am using PC as a router/media center) you can easily configure some kind of dhcp/proxy/etc combination on it and catch the MAC from network clients.

Comment: But my hotspot acts as a router right. and also right now i am in ubuntu and i have created a hotspot and my friend can access it by entering password to it.

Comment: So you are using your laptop as hotpot right now, right?

Comment: Ya i was using.. i want to display a login page when my friend connects to my wifi.

Comment: The classic case - that you have router, which carries out everything related to routing/DHCP/proxy and so on. It can be the low-end PC or the old one. All the other PCs - are clients, getting the internet from the router. Try to read this article: http://aryo.info/labs/captive-portal-using-php-and-iptables.html, it will be helpful.